# Add a Home directory for already created user when no direct root login available

Tags: ubuntu, home-directory, usermod

I have a user account provided by client with unrestricted `sudo` access, but this user has no home directory. I want to create one, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I tried logging in as my normal user and `sudo su`ing  into root, then running

```
 usermod -d /home/user  -m user
```

But it gaves the message `usermod: no changes.` I assume because my user is already logged in?

Other solutions seem to involve removing and re-creating my user account with a home directory,  but again as user would be already logged in I think there may be problems with that approach.

Is there a way to create my user's home directory with the access I have, or do I need to inform my client/provider to recreate my account?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just create a home directory for them and grant them permissions.
`mkdir /home/$user` and then `chown $user:$user /home/$user`.

Take note to replace the group in the `chown` command with something else if required.

Comment: I checked it on my local test instance and it work fine. profile also created automatically.

Comment: For future reference, the normal procedure for creating the home directory and setting up a clean environment is to copy the `/etc/skel` home directory template to the new users home directory i.e. `cp -ar /etc/skel/ /home/$user && chown -R $user:$user /home/$user`  which is what adduser does too when creating a new user account.

Comment: @HBruijn, Yes three files .bashrc, .bash_logout, .profile is not created until you manually copy from /etc/skel

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @HBruijn wrote, you also need to apply proper `chmod` of directory i.e.:

```
cp -ar /etc/skel/ /home/$user && chown -R $user:$user /home/$user && chmod 700 /home/$user
```